# Order of JSF portlets effect the rendering of ice:inputRichText

Tags: jsf, liferay, portlet, icefaces

I have two seperate JSF portlet wars, both have their different liberaries and configuration. Single portlet on page is working fine, but when i place two portlets on same page and if the the portlet using ice:inputRichText is placed first, the RichText doesn't render and throws js errors as following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'updateValue' of undefined
```

While its working fine, when portlet using richText is placed at the end.

Comment: Have you got a URL for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

What version of ICEfaces are you using?

It's a long time I used ICEfaces, but I remember having to include an `<ice:portlet>` tag in the root of your facelet to ensure each portlet is properly namespaced, so the Javascript doesn't clash between different portlets on the page.

Comment: If the content of JSF portlet is not wrapped with <ice:porltet> tag, it causes render-phase exception. But, both my portlets are rendering. The problem is with inputRichText.